# File Upload with Angular Material

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, file-upload, angular-material

I'm writing an web app with AngularJS and angular-material. The problem is that there's no built-in component for file input in angular-material. (I feel that file uploading doesn't fit the material design, but I need it in my app)

Do you have a good solution for this problem?

Comment: input works normally just set the type as file: `<input type=file>`. add this code inside input container.

Comment: I recently found this one: [https://github.com/shuyu/angular-material-fileinput](https://github.com/shuyu/angular-material-fileinput) It fits nice and works like a charm. The docs is simple and direct of how to use it.

Comment: Two years later, and `<input type="file">` does allow the user to select a file, but the button is plain html looking, and not Material styled, and that doesn't work for me at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find a way to avoid styling my own choose file button.

Because I'm using **flowjs** for resumable upload, I'm able to use the "**flow-btn**" directive from **ng-flow**, which gives a choose file button with material design style.

Note that wrapping the input element inside a md-button won't work.

Answer (score 61):

For Angular 6+:

HTML:

```html
<input #csvInput hidden="true" type="file" onclick="this.value=null" (change)="csvInputChange($event)" accept=".csv"/>
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="csvInput.click()">Choose Spreadsheet File (CSV)</button>
```

Component method:

```js
  csvInputChange(fileInputEvent: any) {
    console.log(fileInputEvent.target.files[0]);
  }
```

**Note:** This filters to just allow `.csv` files.

Comment: Can you explain why `onclick="this.value=null"` is necessary?

Comment: It forces a `change` event.  Ex: you choose `me.jpg` and your Angular app displays a preview client side.  You then notice your `me.jpg` isn't cropped correctly, so you modify `me.jpg` in photoshop, then go back to your webapp, click the button and choose `me.jpg` again.  Without setting `this.value=null` your logic to re-render the image on the page would never fire.  So not necessary, but it is good practice IMO.

Answer (score 57):

**Nice solution by [leocaseiro](https://github.com/leocaseiro)**

```
<input class="ng-hide" id="input-file-id" multiple type="file" />
<label for="input-file-id" class="md-button md-raised md-primary">Choose Files</label>
```

[image]

**View in [codepen](http://codepen.io/radin/pen/JXaKob)**

Comment: However, if you want to actually give the user some feedback on the file they selected (like the `<input type="file">` does), then look at other solutions.

Comment: Also, the label doesn't behave correctly with the tab and enter keys, even if you put tabindex="0" on it.

Answer (score 15):

Another example of the solution.
Will look like the following
[image]

CodePen link **[there](http://codepen.io/shepard_one/pen/VKwwVR)**.

```
  <choose-file layout="row">
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" class="ng-hide">
    <md-input-container flex class="md-block">
      <input type="text" ng-model="fileName" disabled>
      <div class="hint">Select your file</div>
    </md-input-container>
    <div>
      <md-button id="uploadButton" class="md-fab md-mini">
        <md-icon class="material-icons">attach_file</md-icon>
      </md-button>
    </div>
  </choose-file>   

.directive('chooseFile', function() {
    return {
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var button = elem.find('button');
        var input = angular.element(elem[0].querySelector('input#fileInput'));

        button.bind('click', function() {
          input[0].click();
        });

        input.bind('change', function(e) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            var files = e.target.files;
            if (files[0]) {
              scope.fileName = files[0].name;
            } else {
              scope.fileName = null;
            }
          });
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Rather than using "disabled" on the input for "fileName" I used ng-readonly="true".  But the idea in itself is the best!

Answer (score 13):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32511030/2147383). It took some time for me to make this approach working, so I hope my answer will save someone's time.

**[DEMO on CodePen](http://codepen.io/juniper/pen/LGEOVb)**

**Directive:**

```
angular.module('app').directive('apsUploadFile', apsUploadFile);

function apsUploadFile() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'upload.file.template.html',
        link: apsUploadFileLink
    };
    return directive;
}

function apsUploadFileLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    var input = $(element[0].querySelector('#fileInput'));
    var button = $(element[0].querySelector('#uploadButton'));
    var textInput = $(element[0].querySelector('#textInput'));

    if (input.length && button.length && textInput.length) {
        button.click(function (e) {
            input.click();
        });
        textInput.click(function (e) {
            input.click();
        });
    }

    input.on('change', function (e) {
        var files = e.target.files;
        if (files[0]) {
            scope.fileName = files[0].name;
        } else {
            scope.fileName = null;
        }
        scope.$apply();
    });
}
```

**upload.file.template.html**

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file" class="ng-hide">
<md-button id="uploadButton"
           class="md-raised md-primary"
           aria-label="attach_file">
    Choose file
</md-button>
<md-input-container md-no-float>
    <input id="textInput" ng-model="fileName" type="text" placeholder="No file chosen" ng-readonly="true">
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: Nice try..But, I feel it does'nt support Multiple files

Answer (score 12):

from jameswyse at https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3310

HTML

```
<input id="fileInput" name="file" type="file" class="ng-hide" multiple>
<md-button id="uploadButton" class="md-raised md-primary"> Choose Files </md-button>
```

CONTROLLER

```
    var link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    const input = element.find('#fileInput');
    const button = element.find('#uploadButton');

    if (input.length && button.length) {
        button.click((e) => input.click());
    }
}
```

Worked for me.

Comment: That's the easiest way. However, I'd switch the md-button for a label for="inputid", so you don't need to bind your click. The Label does but itself.

Eq. <input class="ng-hide" id="FileUploadInput" multiple type="file" /> <label for="FileUploadInput" class="md-button md-raised md-primary">Choose Files</label>

Comment: @LeoCaseiro Care to put that in an answer?

Comment: At least in 2017, the label doesn't seem to behave correctly using the tab / enter key combinations, while the button does.

Answer (score 10):

with Angular material
HTML

```
<div (click)="uploadFile.click()">
   <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Choose File</button>
   <input #uploadFile (change)="upload($event)" type='file' style="display:none"/> 
</div>
```

ts

```
upload(event:Event){
   console.log(event)
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s6e8py?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Perfect example. Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I've join some informations posted here and the possibility of personalize components with Angular Material and this is my contribution without external libs and feedback with the name of the chosen file into field:

[image]

[image]

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="columns">
    <mat-label *ngIf="selectedFiles; else newFile">{{selectedFiles.item(0).name}}</mat-label>
    <ng-template #newFile>
        <mat-label>Choose file</mat-label>
    </ng-template>
    <input matInput disabled>
    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="fileInput.click()">
        <mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <input hidden (change)="selectFile($event)" #fileInput type="file" id="file">
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
selectFile(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
}
```

Comment: Some edit suggestions
this.selectedFiles = event.target.files will not work directly in angular now.
Use  this.selectedFiles = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;

Answer (score 3):

You can change the style by wrapping the input inside a label and change the input display to none. Then, you can specify the text you want to be displayed inside a span element. 
Note: here I used bootstrap 4 button style (btn btn-outline-primary). You can use any style you want.

```
<label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
      <span>Select File</span>
      <input type="file">
</label>

input {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
html:
    <div class="upload">
        <span>upload image</span>
        <input
          #Image
          type="file"
          (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)"
          accept=".jpg,.svg,.png,.jpeg"
        />
        <img
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          *ngIf="imageUrl"
          [src]="imageUrl"
          class="image"
        />
    </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  options = [{ value: "This is value 1", checked: true }];
  statuses = ["control"];

  // name = "Angular";//
  fileToUpload: any;
  imageUrl: any;
  handleFileInput(file: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = file.item(0);

    //Show image preview
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.imageUrl = event.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileToUpload);
  }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

Another hacked solution, though might be a little cleaner by implementing a Proxy button:

**HTML:**

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file">
<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="upload()">
  <label>AwesomeButtonName</label>
</md-button>
```

**JS:**

```
app.controller('NiceCtrl', function ( $scope) {
  $scope.upload = function () {
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).click();
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to all the answers above (which is why I made it a community wiki), it is probably best to mark any `input<type="text">` with `tabindex="-1"`, especially if using readonly instead of disabled (and perhaps the `<input type="file">`, although it should be hidden, it is still in the document, apparently).  Labels did not act correctly when using the tab / enter key combinations, but the button did.  So if you are copying one of the other solutions on this page, you may want to make those changes.

Answer (score 0):

File uploader with AngularJs Material and a mime type validation:

Directive:

```
function apsUploadFile() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        require:['ngModel', 'apsUploadFile'],
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            label: '@',
            mimeType: '@',
        },
        templateUrl: '/build/html/aps-file-upload.html',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        controller: function($scope) {
            var self = this;

            this.model = null;

            this.setModel = function(ngModel) {
                this.$error = ngModel.$error;

                ngModel.$render = function() {
                    self.model = ngModel.$viewValue;
                };

                $scope.$watch('ctrl.model', function(newval) {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(newval);
                });
            };
        },
        link: apsUploadFileLink
    };
    return directive;
}

function apsUploadFileLink(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {

    var ngModelCtrl = controllers[0];
    var apsUploadFile = controllers[1];

    apsUploadFile.inputname = attrs.name;
    apsUploadFile.setModel(ngModelCtrl);

    var reg;
    attrs.$observe('mimeType', function(value) {
        var accept = value.replace(/,/g,'|');
        reg = new RegExp(accept, "i");
        ngModelCtrl.$validate();
    });

    ngModelCtrl.$validators.mimetype = function(modelValue, viewValue) {

        if(modelValue.data == null){
            return apsUploadFile.valid = true;
        }

        if(modelValue.type.match(reg)){
            return apsUploadFile.valid = true;
        }else{
            return apsUploadFile.valid = false;
        }

    };

    var input = $(element[0].querySelector('#fileInput'));
    var button = $(element[0].querySelector('#uploadButton'));
    var textInput = $(element[0].querySelector('#textInput'));

    if (input.length && button.length && textInput.length) {
        button.click(function(e) {
            input.click();
        });
        textInput.click(function(e) {
            input.click();
        });
    }

    input.on('change', function(e) {

        //scope.fileLoaded(e);
        var files = e.target.files;

        if (files[0]) {
            ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.filename = scope.filename = files[0].name;
            ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.type = files[0].type;
            ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.size = files[0].size;

            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function () {
                ngModelCtrl.$viewValue.data = fileReader.result;
                ngModelCtrl.$validate();
            };
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);

            ngModelCtrl.$render();
        } else {
            ngModelCtrl.$viewValue = null;
        }

        scope.$apply();
    });

}
app.directive('apsUploadFile', apsUploadFile);
```

html template:

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file" name="ctrl.inputname" class="ng-hide">
<md-input-container md-is-error="!ctrl.valid">
    <label>{@{label}@}</label>
    <input id="textInput" ng-model="ctrl.model.filename" type="text" ng-readonly="true">
    <div ng-messages="ctrl.$error" ng-transclude></div>
</md-input-container>
<md-button id="uploadButton" class="md-icon-button md-primary" aria-label="attach_file">
    <md-icon class="material-icons">cloud_upload</md-icon>
</md-button>
```

Exemple:

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row">
    <aps-upload-file name="strip" ng-model="cardDesign.strip" label="Strip" mime-type="image/png" class="md-block">
        <div ng-message="mimetype" class="md-input-message-animation ng-scope" style="opacity: 1; margin-top: 0px;">Your image must be PNG.</div>
    </aps-upload-file>
</div>
```