# upload file with angular 5 and material

Tags: angular, file-upload, material-design, angular-material

I'm working with Angular 5 and [material library](https://material.angular.io/). I need to upload a file, but in the documentation, I didn't find an explanation to accomplish this task.

Is anybody that have the same need that can suggest me a good tutorial or documentation?

Tnx

Comment: (Not using Material but it might help others: https://gist.github.com/stuartaccent/51afc6b17d89d4dc6f3968ede5d789b6 / https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-file-upload-queue?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: This has been answered in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867194/file-upload-with-angular-material/67990947#67990947). You can refer to my answer there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a nice library that handles this requirement that also follows Marerial Design. See attached link:

[TeraData file-upload example](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/file-upload)

Comment: Very nice package. Loads of love <3.

Comment: [FileInput](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/v3/#/components/file-input/overview) is the current component.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I personalized a component with Angular Material without external libs and feedback with the name of the chosen file into field:

[image]
[image]

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="columns">
    <mat-label *ngIf="selectedFiles; else newFile">{{selectedFiles.item(0).name}}</mat-label>
    <ng-template #newFile>
        <mat-label>Choose file</mat-label>
    </ng-template>
    <input matInput disabled>
    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="fileInput.click()">
        <mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <input hidden (change)="selectFile($event)" #fileInput type="file" id="file">
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
selectFile(event) {
    this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
}
```