# How to use input type file in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

**How to use input type file in angular material**

Hi, I am using angular material for designing. when i go on angular material site there no input type file element. anyone know about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867194/file-upload-with-angular-material

Comment: Yes, Possible but i want like this format      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="file" placeholder="Choose File">
      </mat-form-field>

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Angular Material does not support yet a workaround for file upload.
There are alternative to archieve this. e.g using external libraries.

**angular-material-fileupload**: [link to npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-fileupload)

*Supported features*:

- Drag and drop
- common uploads
- progress bar
- file size and more...

**ngx-material-file-input**: [Link to repository](https://github.com/merlosy/ngx-material-file-input)

*Supported features*:

- `ngx-mat-file-input` component, to use inside Angular Material `mat-form-field`
- a `FileValidator` with `maxContentSize`, to limit the file size
- a `ByteFormatPipe` to format the file size in a human-readable format
- and more small minor features...

**Update**

See the answer here if you just need a workaround without external library
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53546417/6432698

Answer (score 121):

Here is a workaround if all you want is a nicely displayed file input button.

Html

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="fileInput.click()">Choose File</button>
<input hidden (change)="onFileSelected()" #fileInput type="file" id="file">
```

Component

```
onFileSelected() {
  const inputNode: any = document.querySelector('#file');

  if (typeof (FileReader) !== 'undefined') {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      this.srcResult = e.target.result;
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(inputNode.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Inspired by this Angular Material Github Issue comment
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3262#issuecomment-309000588

Comment: Wouldn't it be better using the Angular ay instead of query selector ? Like @ViewChild ?

Comment: I think it will better to add `$event` in `onFileSelected($event)` function, so you don't required `id="file"`in input.

Comment: This solution can be simplified a bit. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72047999

Comment: You could also pass the file list directly to the method on change by using the template reference `(change)="onFileSelected(fileInput.files)"`

Answer (score 14):

Building on @JackMorrissey's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53546417/3727722), I found a more simplified solution:

**HTML**:

```html
<button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="fileInput.click()">Choose File</button>
<input hidden (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileInput type="file">
<span class="file-name">{{selectedFile?.name}}</span>
```

**TypeScript**:

```js
selectedFile: any = null;

onFileSelected(event: any): void {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0] ?? null;

}
```

**CSS**:

```css
.file-name {
    margin-left: 1rem; /* or whatever margin you require */
}
```

---

Output:

[image: file select]

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest you to checkout [@angular-material-components/file-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-material-components/file-input).

It is very Angular Material Compliant.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Made more sense to just [style the default input element of type file using the ::file-selector-button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button) to look like the angular material button. Also, this way accounts for UX which lets the user know that the file to upload has been added to the form by displaying the file name.

> P.S. Style was copied from the declarations after inspecting the
> angular mat-raised-button

```css
input[type="file"]::file-selector-button {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
  background: #ffd740;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 64px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: visible;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: background 400ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1), box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  margin: 1rem;
}


/*  fallback for older browsers supporting the -webkit prefix */

input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
  background: #ffd740;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 64px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: visible;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: background 400ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1), box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  margin: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="fileUpload">Add file</label>
  <input type="file" id="fileUpload">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this method (with Tailwind CSS). There are two inputs here. The first one is transparent file input. The file input is the front side by z-index. The back side has another input (matInput).

```
<mat-form-field class="w-full">
    <input
        type="file"
        class="absolute top-0 z-10 h-full w-full cursor-pointer opacity-0"
        accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png"
    />
    <mat-label>{{ matLabel }}</mat-label>
    <input
        matInput
        cdkFocusInitial
        class="z-0"
    />
    <mat-icon matSuffix class="mr-2">cloud_upload</mat-icon>
    <mat-hint class="mat-form-field-hint-end"
        >JPEG / JPG / PNG</mat-hint
    >
</mat-form-field>
```

[image: If you click to input then you can open directly the file dialog.]
**If you click to input then you can open directly the file dialog.*

Answer (score 1):

It's funny, but in my case it worked with attr binding `[attr.type]="'file'"` instead of setting attribute directly `type="file"`

Comment: Works, but the styles are all messed up

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use some strange workaround, then just dont place `input` into the    `mat-form-field`. You can place it outside the `mat-form-field` but still include the value into the `FormGroup`. Check the example

```
<form [formGroup]="someForm"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <!--input outside the form-field-->
            <input type="file" (Change)="onChange($event)"/>
            <mat-form-field>
                <!--input inside the form-field-->
                <input matInput formControlName="someFCN">
            </mat-form-field>
            <button mat-raised-button>Submit</button>
</form>




import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

someForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.someForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          someFCN: [{ value:'', disabled: false },Validators.required],
          file: { value:'', disabled: false }
        });
}

onChange(event: Event) {
    /*not sure what you want to do with file, i'll just set
    selected file´s name as value, but obviously u can do much more than just get file´s name.*/
    
    this.someForm.controls['file'].setValue(event.target.files[0].name);
}

onSubmit() {
    return this.someForm.getRawValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create directive -

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Inject, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFileUpload]'
})
export class FileUploadDirective {
  @Output() fileContent: EventEmitter<ArrayBuffer | string> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const input = this.document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'file';
      input.onchange = ev => {
        const file = (ev.target as HTMLInputElement).files?.item(0);
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = e => {
          this.fileContent.next(reader.result!);
          input.value = '';
        };
        switch (file?.type) {
          case 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet':
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file!);
            break;
          default:
            reader.readAsText(file!);
        }
      };
      input.click();
      input.remove();
    });
  }
}
```

and then use it like -

```html
 <button appFileUpload (fileContent)="uploadDump($event)" mat-menu-item><mat-icon>upload_file</mat-icon></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick and easy way to solve this problem.

I make the input for the file look like an input for the text.

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field> 
   <mat-label>Select file</mat-label>
   <input matInput readonly type="text" id="fakeFileInput" (click)="hiddenInput.click()">
   <input hidden type="file" accept=".csv" #hiddenInput (change)="GetFileOnLoad($event)">
   <mat-icon matSuffix>folder_open</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TypeScript:**

```
public GetFileOnLoad(event: any) {
var file = event.target.files[0];
var element = document.getElementById("fakeFileInput") as HTMLInputElement | null;
if(element != null) {
  element.value = file?.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more modern API `Blob.text` which can do this in a simpler way:

```html
<button mat-button (click)="fileInput.click()">Choose File</button>
<input type="file" #fileInput hidden (change)="onFileSelected($event)">
```

```js
onFileSelected = (event: Event & { target: HTMLInputElement }) => {
  event.target.files?.[0]?.text().then(text => {
    // use text
  });
};
```